# Polylines are being drawn randomly and in random location on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

I am working diligently on figuring how to get lines to show on my map.  I am attempting to draw a line from touches began to touches end.

At the moment I am taking the coords of where I touch, add it to an array, take the cords of where touch end, add it to an array then draw the line. This is my code below.

When I ran the code sadly my line did not show.  However while sitting wondering what I was missing (cause my coords are being saved to the array) I kept swiping my screen in frustration and suddenly a line appeared! I closed the program and did the same thing again and as far as I can tell, lines are being drawn randomly, and at the wrong coordinates.

I changed

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D obh1=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake
    (startTouch.latitude, startTouch.longitude);
```

to

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D obh1=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake
    (startTouch.longitude, startTouch.latitude);
```

to see if I was somehow mixing my coords but the same thing is happening. The lines are being drawn in random locations.

Would appreciate if someone could offer me a little help to solve this.

I have done some work and this is what I have come up with. The 4 lines points you see appear when I click on the map. They are the touches end, the touches begin. I have no idea where they are coming from but not from my code.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches began");

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Get the specific point that was touched
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
     //convert toc
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startTouch
    =[self.map convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:_map];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D obh1=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startTouch.latitude, startTouch.longitude);
    [arrayOfLine addObject: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:obh1]];
    NSLog(@"array: %@", arrayOfLine);
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches END");


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D endTouch
    =[self.map convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:_map];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D obh=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endTouch.latitude, endTouch.longitude);
        [arrayOfLine addObject: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:obh]];
        NSLog(@"array: %@", arrayOfLine);

            MKPolyline *polygon = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:&obh count:[arrayOfLine count]];

    [_map addOverlay:polygon];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        overlayView.strokeColor     = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        overlayView.lineWidth       = 3;

        return overlayView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random lines *are* coming from the code in question.

The main problem is in `touchesEnded` in this section:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D obh=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endTouch.latitude, endTouch.longitude);
[arrayOfLine addObject: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:obh]];
NSLog(@"array: %@", arrayOfLine);

MKPolyline *polygon = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:&obh count:[arrayOfLine count]];
```

When calling `polylineWithCoordinates`, the code is giving the address of `obh` which is a *single* `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct but the `count` is set to the number of objects in `arrayOfLine` which would most likely be two (touch begin + touch end).

The `polylineWithCoordinates` method is expecting a plain C array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs.

Currently, the code is giving the method only a single struct but the count tells the method to also use the bytes in memory following the *single* struct as coordinates in the array.  The bytes in memory following `obh` are most likely going to be random values which translate to meaningless coordinates and so you get random lines  or no lines at all.

To fix this, you need to construct a plain C array from `arrayOfLine` (an Objective-C `NSArray`).
Here's one way to do it:

```
//REPLACE this existing line with the code below:
//MKPolyline *polygon = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:&obh count:[arrayOfLine count]];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[arrayOfLine.count];

for (int c = 0; c < arrayOfLine.count; c++)
{
    NSValue *v = [arrayOfLine objectAtIndex:c];
    coords[c] = v.MKCoordinateValue;
}

MKPolyline *polygon = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:[arrayOfLine count]];
```

---

A few other points not directly causing a problem:

1. In `touchesBegan`, creating `obh1` is unnecessary.  `startTouch` is already a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that you can add to the array.
2. In `touchesEnded`, creating `obh` is unnecessary.  `endTouch` is already a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that you can add to the array.
3. Currently, `arrayOfLine` is not being cleared at any point.  This means whenever touches end, *all* lines the user has drawn are re-drawn (and connected together).  Not sure what the intention is but if you only want the current begin+end touch pair to be drawn, then at the top of `touchesBegan`, do `[arrayOfLine removeAllObjects];`.
4. Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO` on the map view otherwise it may interfere with the touch methods and cause strange behavior (like `touchesEnded` not getting called).

Comment: thank you for this I have fixed 1,2&4 and point 3 was by design. If I am allowed to use you as a sounding board for a few tips I would appreciate it. The point of what I am doing is to be able to draw on a map to direct you to someplace, As you know the road will be curvy etc. However this only draws straight lines. I had drawn on a view, and the lines were perfect cause I could bend them how i like but i could not draw it on a map. Would you recommend a transparent map with a view underneath it if I was to draw directions for someone? then again how would zoomin be handled

Comment: For point 3: In that case, you should at least remove all existing overlays before adding the new one.  Otherwise, you end up with multiple overlapping overlays.  Overlay[1] has line 1, overlay[2] has lines 1 to 2, overlay[3] has lines 1 to 3, etc.  Right before the `addOverlay`, do `[_map removeOverlays:_map.overlays];`.

Comment: It's not clear why the user would have to draw lines on the map to direct them to someplace.  If you want the line to follow the user's finger as it curves, try updating the array and replacing the overlay in touchesMoved instead of touchesEnded.

Comment: Still, it's not clear why the user has to draw to get directions.  The MKDirections class will give you the MKPolylines needed to draw the directions to someplace.  Research and try some more things out and then post a new, detailed question (with code).

Comment: Say you go over to tokoyo, and you want to know where the gym is or some little back alley not on the map and you ask someone. (I use tokoyo but maybe i shouldnt say some little country where everything will not be aavailable on google places) I want an individual to be able to trace a route from your location to the desired location. this is my orginal intention

Comment: I was wrong when i said user having to draw, I was thinking of a real world example if you had your phone off to someone to draw directions to the cities wishing well. Thinngs that may not exactly be marked on the map